# SQL Server / SQL Azure Schema Compare

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, azure-sql-database, schema-compare

I'd like to compare schemas between SQL Server 2012 and SQL Azure, but I get this error in Visual Studio 2013:

> A project which specifies SQL Server 2012 as the target platform cannot be published to SQL Azure.

[image]

Is it possible to compare these 2 database types?

Comment: The only way I've been able to do this is to import the SQL 2012 DB to a database project targetting SQL Azure, then compare the project to SQL Azure. Would love to know if there's a better way.

Comment: Thanks @AnthonyChu.  I'll give that a try, but it does sound cumbersome.  I hope someone can still share a more convenient way.

Comment: The way I do it is as described by Anthony, compare a database project and Azure. It is good practice to have your DB schema in the project and source control anyway.

Comment: @AnthonyChu, if you copy your comment to the answer box, I'll mark is as the accepted answer.

Comment: @Craig Thanks. And good point regarding source controlling the schema. I don't think enough people do it. I do wish there was a way to compare an on-prem SQL Server DB to a SQL Azure DB in an adhoc manner though... Just being able to see the diff without ability to update would've been nice.

Comment: You can compare a local database to Azure using RedGate schema compare, but that costs extra $$

Answer (score 71, accepted):

There actually is a non-cumbersome method to overcome this problem. Just open up the [schema compare options](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/312ed73e-f70d-4072-ab2b-77d417dbfee5/error-with-schema-compare-a-project-which-specifies-sql-server-2008-as-the-target-platform-cannot?forum=ssdt) and make sure the **"Allow incompatible platform"** box is checked

[image: SQL Compare Options - General]

Comment: Fantastic!  That was the ticket.

Comment: Genius my friend, pure genius

Comment: Anyone want to post how to even get to Schema Compare Options?

Comment: This error can also occur if you are trying to migrate a database from SQL Server to Azure SQL Database using the tools available within Visual Studio SQL Server Object Explorer. In the Advanced button this option also exists.

Answer (score 4):

Need more reputation to comment, sorry for redundant answer: this window can not be found in VS options. Start comparison and click options button
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The only way I've been able to do this is to import the SQL 2012 DB to a database project targetting SQL Azure, then compare the project to the SQL Azure database.